# ThreeJS material with shadows but no lights

Tags: three.js

I want a material with:

- Textures
- Not receiving lights
- Receiving shadows

I tried with the following library materials:

- MeshBasicMaterial: Does not support shadows
- MeshLamberMaterial: If you disable lights (material.lights = false) it also disables shadows
- ShadowMaterial: Does not support textures

Is a custom ShaderMaterial the only way to achieve it?

Comment: you cannot have shadows without lights

Comment: _Not receiveing lights. Receiving shadows._ Sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: @gaitat: It's possible, if you're doing non-photorealistic rendering and want to achieve a flat look without losing shadows.

Comment: @gaitat of course I can, I have lights in the scene but I don't want them to render, just to get shadows.

Comment: Really, I can't understand the down votes, I think I've perfectly explained the question, and even some people tell that it is not posible getting positive votes, when thats not true... of course it is posible since this is webGL and I've already seen it, I'm just asking if there is an easy way to do this with Three, or I have to use a custom shader...

Comment: @Pablo Then maybe better to put it like “not affected by lights” instead of “not receiving lights”. And adding a picture with the desired result will help the others to understand what you want. The link to the web page, where you’ve seen such effect, will be also helpful.

Comment: What would be the difference in the material between a part that is in shadow and a part that is not? The difference is the amount of light...You are going to have to more clearly explain the material you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In three.js, as in real life, shadows are the absence of light. So for a built-in three.js material to receive shadows, it must respond to light.

However, you can modify a built-in material's shader to achieve the effect you want with just a few lines of code. Here is an example to get you started:

```
THREE.ShaderLib[ 'lambert' ].fragmentShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ 'lambert' ].fragmentShader.replace(

    `vec3 outgoingLight = reflectedLight.directDiffuse + reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse + totalEmissiveRadiance;`,

    `#ifndef CUSTOM
        vec3 outgoingLight = reflectedLight.directDiffuse + reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse + totalEmissiveRadiance;
    #else
        vec3 outgoingLight = diffuseColor.rgb * ( 1.0 - 0.5 * ( 1.0 - getShadowMask() ) ); // shadow intensity hardwired to 0.5 here
    #endif`

);
```

Then, to use it:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture } );
material.defines = material.defines || {};
material.defines.CUSTOM = "";
```

In spite of its name, this material will behave like `MeshBasicMaterial`, but will darken when it is in shadow. And furthermore, `MeshLambertMaterial` will still work as expected.

three.js r.88

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for, and so much simpler than creating a new shader from scratch.

Comment: I ended up using the snippet from @WestLangley, but combined it with the original, so unlit environments still produce good results. Looks really well with foliage combined with ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE :)

https://gist.github.com/haroldiedema/b8f94c53f2a28b6278860622dad4ad8e

Answer (score 3):

In a past version, maybe .72, you could cast and receive shadows with the MeshBasicMaterial. It was simple. Then the concept of ambient light changed in three.js and MeshBasicMaterial could no longer support shadows.

THREE.ShadowMaterial was introduced to compensate for the limitation. It works great! But it really only works on PlaneGeometry because by it's nature, THREE.ShadowMaterial is transparent, so the shadows cast inside and outside the object3d with ShadowMaterial are seen.

The idea is that you use two meshes, one with the MeshBasicMaterial, and the other with ShadowMaterial.

```
shape = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),

basicMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000
}),
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(shape, basicMaterial),

shadowMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({opacity:.2}),
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(shape, shadowMaterial),
```

You can see an example of the problem, here: https://jsfiddle.net/7d47oLkh/

The shadows cast at the bottom of the box are incorrect for the use-case.

The answer is, NO. There is no easy way to support full-bright basic materials that also accept and cast a shadow in three.js.