# Three.js - DoubleSide Material same lightning

Tags: three.js, glsl

This is somewhat a follow-up on this [ThreeJS material with shadows but no lights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367181/threejs-material-with-shadows-but-no-lights)

The question is really simple. I have foliage in my scene that is made up of a couple of planes in a cross, and I need both sides of the plane lit equally, but still being affected by shadow.

With an unmodified shader, the scene looks like this:
[image: unmodified shader]

As you can see, the front and back side of the planes are not equally lit, causing the "hard edges" to show.

Based on the answer from @WestLangely in the SO question mentioned above, I was able to create the desired effect like so:

```
THREE.ShaderLib[ 'lambert' ].fragmentShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ 'lambert' ].fragmentShader.replace(
`vec3 outgoingLight = reflectedLight.directDiffuse + reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse + totalEmissiveRadiance;`,
`
#ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED
    reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse = getAmbientLightIrradiance( ambientLightColor );
    reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse *= BRDF_Diffuse_Lambert( diffuseColor.rgb );

    reflectedLight.directDiffuse = diffuseColor.rgb;
    reflectedLight.directDiffuse *= BRDF_Diffuse_Lambert( diffuseColor.rgb ) * getShadowMask();

    vec3 outgoingLight = (reflectedLight.directDiffuse + reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse + totalEmissiveRadiance).rgb * ( 1.0 - 0.45 * ( 1.0 - getShadowMask() ) );
#else
    vec3 outgoingLight = reflectedLight.directDiffuse + reflectedLight.indirectDiffuse + totalEmissiveRadiance;
#endif
`
);
```

Which produced the following result:
[image: modified shader]

As you can see, the "hard edges" are gone, and the foliage looks a lot better now.

However, something is causing them not to be properly affected by lights anymore. Making the environment dark and adding a simple `PointLight`, gives the following result:

[image: modified shader with pointlight]

The dark foliage meshes shown above should be properly lit as a whole.

I'm sure there is a better way to go about this, but my knowledge of GLSL only goes so far, especially when it comes to modifying Three.js shaders.

TL;DR: How can I make a material be equally lit on both sides, providing `THREE.DoubleSide` is set as `side` on the material, while the entire mesh is still affected by shadows?

Thanks in advance!